# Are there any podcast about Delphi?

Tags: delphi

Were can I find some good Podcasts that talk about program with Delphi & the whole software lifecycle

Comment: I am the host of the Podcast @ Delphi.org, if you have any show suggestions or requests please let me know!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Podcast at Delphi

http://www.delphi.org/

Also, you specified "software lifecycle" so there is another great podcast I like which is really language agnostic and that is Software Engineering Radio:

http://www.se-radio.net/